# Interop sending string from C# to C++

Tags: c#, c++, string, interop

I want to send a string from C# to a function in a native C++ DLL.

Here is my code:
The C# side:

```
[DllImport(@"Native3DHandler.dll", EntryPoint = "#22", 
    CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern void func1(byte[] path);

public void func2(string path)
{
   ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
   byte[] arr = encoding.GetBytes(path);
   func1(this.something, arr);
}
```

The C++ side:

```
void func1(char *path)
{
    //...
}
```

What I get in the C++ side is an empty string, every time, no matter what I send.
Help?

Thanks.

Comment: Aldo, for more accurate passing parameters definition, you can use [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] , etc. See MSDN for more

Comment: How are you determining that the string is empty on the C++ side?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have 2 issues.  The first is your native C++ uses an ANSI string but you are specifying unicode.  Secondly, it's easiest to just marshal a string as a string.

Try changing the DllImport to the following

```
[DllImport(
  @"Native3DHandler.dll", 
  EntryPoint = "#22",  
  CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
private static extern void func1(void* something, [In] string path);
```

Answer (score 2):

Works fine for me with no extra marshalling instructions in VS2008:

C# side:

```
[DllImport("Test.dll")]
public static extern void getString(StringBuilder theString, int bufferSize);

func()
{
  StringBuilder tstStr = new StringBuilder(BufSize);
  getString(tstStr, BufSize);
}
```

C++ side:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void getString(char* str, int bufferSize)
{
  strcpy_s(str, bufferSize, "FOOBAR");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your declaration is wrong.  The parameter should be of type string, and you should set the character set encoding to Ansi, like so:

```
[DllImport(@"Native3DHandler.dll", EntryPoint = "#22", 
    CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
private static extern void func1(string path);
```

This assumes that you are not modifying the contents of the path variable in your C++ code.  Then, you pass the string parameter directly (no need for the wrapper).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to send a string, just declare func1's parameter as a string. If you want to receive a string, declare it as a StringBuilder and allocate enough buffer space for what you want to receive.

Answer (score 0):

Default Marshaling for Strings
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9ts558h.aspx