# Encoding from C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++

I am sending a series of `char arrays` from C++ to my C# program.

The c++ functions look something like this:

**ReturnChar.cpp**

```
extern "C" RETURNCHAR_API char* testString()
{
    return test;
}
```

**ReturnChar.h**

```
extern "C" RETURNCHAR_API char* __cdecl testString();
```

**ReturnChar Import C#**

```
public static class ImportTest
    {
        [DllImport("ReturnChar.dll", EntryPoint = "testString", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static unsafe extern char* testString();
    }
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public unsafe MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            try
            {

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(new string(ImportTest.testString()));
                textBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

I get the result actually, but looks like there is a problem of encoding between C++ and C#. How can I resolve this?

I don't intend to use `wchar_t` in my C++ program, because I have the operations being done on char arrays. Can I somehow encode this in C#?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Interop sending string from C# to C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683013/interop-sending-string-from-c-sharp-to-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *should* be using `wchar_t` throughout in your C++ program, and perform your operations on `wchar_t` arrays instead.

That said, you need to add `CharSet = CharSet.Ansi` to the `DllImport` parameters.